# Não consigo enviar array JSON para pagina PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Boa noite,

Estou tentando enviar um array de codigos simples (2,5,7,etc) em formato JSon para uma página php atraves de uma requisicao Ajax mas não consigo.

Meu JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enviArray() {

        cod_jogador.sort();
        var meuArray = JSON.stringify(cod_jogador);
        var x;

        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        httpRequest.open("GET", "selecao.php", true);
        httpRequest.send("x=" + meuArray);

    };
</script>
```

O `cod_jogador` é o vetor com os valores.

Meu HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
    <button type="button" name="" value="" class="button" onclick="enviArray()">Teste</button>
</div>
```

Na pagina `selecao.php` eu tenho a variavel criada para receber o JSON:

```
$array = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
echo "$array";
```

Porém sempre que eu dou echo em qualquer variavel no `GET` (ja tentei com `POST` tb), ele sempre me retorna indefinido. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

Nesse exemplo, é utilizado o metodo POST.

HTML

```
<div id="demo">
    <button type="button" name="" value="" class="button" onclick="enviArray()">Teste</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enviArray() {

    var cod_jogador = ["1", "2", "3"];
    cod_jogador.sort();
    var meuArray = "x=" + JSON.stringify(cod_jogador); 

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "selecao.php", true);    
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(meuArray);
};
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($_POST["x"]);
echo json_encode($obj);
exit();
```

Comment: Oliveira, muito obrigado kra. Funcionou aqui. Estava ha dias buscando essa solucao, me salvou. Grande abraco e que Deus lhe pague

Answer (score 0):

Como você está enviando informações para o servidor, utilize os verbos HTTP corretos para a requisição que em seu caso é o verbo **POST**. Além de especificar o verbo HTTP, você precisa "dizer" ao servidor qual o tipo de conteúdo que está enviado, para isso é necessário utilizar o cabeçalho (header) `Content-Type`.

```
function enviArray() {

    cod_jogador.sort();
    var meuJson = JSON.stringify({codigos: cod_jogador});

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    httpRequest.open("POST", "selecao.php");
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.send(meuJson);
};
```

O seu arquivo php deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST["codigos"], true);
print_r($array); //Não é possível utilizar o "echo" em um array, somente em seus valores: echo $array[0].
```